# How to collect all tweets in English using twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I want to collect all tweets in English using tweepy. Twitter search API can be used here, but I don't know what to give in 'query' part of api. From documentation I understand that this part is required.

How to handle this query part and collect all English tweets?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gather *all* Tweets in English - that's impossible without access to Twitter's [GNIP](https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/) platform.

What you can do, is use the [streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview) to get a [sample of all English Tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#language).

Comment: By all I mean "all accessible" tweets in English. From the API documentation I figured the query parameter is compulsary to add. I don't want any specific topic related tweets. I want all tweets (within rate limit).

Comment: I have to disagree on this one. The `FilteredStream` does provide ALL the tweets matching a set of criteria if these criteria does not return more than 1% of the total tweets.

If the criteria does match more than 1% of the total tweet, twitter will send you a "limit" json that will let you know the number of tweets that were not returned.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do this with Tweepy but if you can directly invoke a Twitter endpoint you just have to add the `lang` parameter as followed :

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=your_search&lang=en

Comment: Thanks Linvi. Just one quick question, what should we supply in 'q' parameter? Sorry if my question looks very naive.

Comment: You should simply provide the search that you want to do. Let say you want to search for `starwars` you search would be https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=starwars&lang=en